# csv file written using python , is empty when opened in linux

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, csv

i have copied the values from list to csv file like

there are 2 lists say

```py
list1 =['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n']
list2 = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12','13']
```

and i am writting the 2 lists to csv file using the below code

```py
import csv
from itertools import izip
with open('output1.csv', 'wb') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(izip(list1, list2))
```

when i open output1.csv in linux after executing the above thing , it is empty

but when i print it , using print(open("output1.csv").read()) in python script is printing the contents of the csv file propery

can you please let me know why the file is empty when i opened it in linux

Comment: Why `b` flag in the file opening mode? Why bytes?

Comment: even if i remove b means if it is modified in script like below with open('output1.csv', 'w') as f: , then also not working

Comment: Is the code indentation correct? Or did you make a mistake in this question?

Comment: ya it is correct , in question it came like that , actually i am able to read the output through open("output1.csv").read() , but file is empty when opened in linux vi output1.csv

Comment: `open("output1.csv")`qualifies as opening the file. If you are unable to open it with vi maybe your vi installation is corrupt or you are not using it correctly.

Comment: Added code block

Answer (score 1):

Next time when you are stuck then please be more specific about the error and output you expect so we don't have to waste time assuming your expected output. Now coming to the your problem `when i open output1.csv in linux after executing the above thing , it is empty` I think you need to read up more about [iterators](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) and also about [file operations](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html). So running your script in my machine gave me this error which is pretty easy to understand.

```
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

Python and it's errors are so readable isn't it !? This error was correct as python was expecting a bytes-like object as the error says! Change that to `w+` ( and read more about permissions in the links given in the answer).
Now this `writer.writerows(izip(list1, list2))` has to understood clearly ( also provided in the links in this answer). When life gives you an iterator, you just iterate it! Grab a reference to iterate the iterator and you are good. Please read more about it.

```
import csv
from itertools import izip

list1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n']
list2 = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13']

with open('output1.csv', 'w+') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows([i for i in izip(list1, list2)]) # your homework to figure out what this means and does.
```

Let me know if this answer worked for you by accepting it!

Cheers!

Comment: No again the csv files are empty , above solution dint help to solve the problem

Comment: What did you try actually ? Are there any errors ? What about helping me helping you with a traceback ?

Comment: No errors are there , i can see the output of file through readlines  but the file is empty when i open though vi editor